# Show only completely visible UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a custom tableView, but the way it's designed makes the bottom and top part ugly when only half of the cell is visible. See picture for reference:

[image: tableView]

I want the bottom part (and the top after crolling) only visible when you can see 100% of the cell.

I tried this to check if the cells were completely visible, but I believe cellForRowAtIndexPath creates the reusableCells when it's partly visible and isn't called again when it's fully visible:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:ChooseStoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChooseStoryCell

    var cellRect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    var completelyVisible = CGRectContainsRect(self.tableView.bounds, cellRect)

    if completelyVisible == true {
        myCell.hidden = false
        myCell.backgroundColor = Color.sharedColors().colorsArray[5]
        myCell.storyLabel.text = stories[indexPath.row].name
        myCell.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }
    else{
        myCell.hidden = true
    }
```

How I would go forward with this? 
Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Try adjusting the height of the cells to fir properly on the screen

Comment: That wouldn't matter when I scroll anyways. At any given time, I don't want to see a cell that's only partly visible. The edges of the tableView seems too sharp then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your table view inside a parent UIView. A margin from top of tableview to top of parent view should be equal to what height of your cells is, same from bottom, the width of table view should be same as its parent's view, left and right margins equals to zero. So there is just extra space at top / bottom to display a cell.

On tableview set clipsToBounds to NO, on parent view make sure that clipsToBounds is set to YES.

The behavior should be like this, when scrolling the cell will be visible until it reaches the top boundary of that parent view and disappear at once.

Alternatively, you can also just reduce height of your tableview, move it down and set clipsToBounds to NO. It should do it. But I prefer to embed in View to be sure that nothing will be display outside.

Comment: That worked! :) Do you happen to know how I would animate a fade in on the cells that appear? It's very snappy atm.

Comment: Use - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView method (be sure to setup tableview's delegate). On that view take up array of visibleCells. Take the first and last cells and you change alpha settings according to a formula that will map the Alpha to the relative position of the Cell.

Comment: I just noticed now that with this method, the top and bottom cells are only "clickable" at the areas which would otherwise be visible. Even though they are visible, I can only click on certain parts. 

I can't find a solutions for this anywhere, do you happen to know what to do?

Comment: Try to put a button in the cell and see if he is clickable when the cell is on that zone. If yes, you can use buttons is your cells (invisible matching background). On cellforrowatindexpath, set up the tag pf the button to be the row of the cell (this works only if you have 1 section) and on the button target method you can then get back the row by using [sender tag]

Comment: The button isn't clickable either. Here are two examples: http://imgur.com/a/8eWB3. In the first example is, the whole cell is clickable. In the second, I have scrolled up, and now only the bottom part is clickable.

Comment: Ok, i see. Unfortunately I don't have my comp as I am in vacation, I cannot test. Try to see with hitTest method. If you catch hittest event on the view which is embedding the table view, you can forward touch which are on those 2 particular zones to first and last visible cells. You can also do that with 2 transparents buttons

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code just came out of my mind. Not tested.

The basic idea is to see the intersection of the cell's frame and the table view's bounds and if the result is the cell's frame, then the cell frame is completely visible.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var cellRect = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        var completelyVisible = cellRect.rectByIntersecting(tableView.bounds) == cellRect

        if completelyVisible == true {
            myCell.contentView.hidden = false
        }
        else{
            myCell.contentView.hidden = true
        }

        return myCell
    }
```